# CloudBasic AWS RDS to EC2 SQL Server replication fails w/ transport-level error

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, database-replication

We are getting very close to go live and we are using CloudBasic from the AWS Marketplace to replicate a number of large databases from primary RDS SQL Server into multiple EC2 SQL Server read-replicas for high availability. The initial seeding runs to a point and fails on some large tables with below error, before the process transitions to continuous change tracking.

CloudBasic Runtime Logs >>Transfer to Destination DB ERROR: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Any advanced CloudBasic configuration option that can resolve this issues ? 
Or.. is there a way to dial down the number of records being pulled to have a possible trickle effect which can possibly help to deal with the network/connectivity issue ?